# Network loss during AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance

i decide to allow the progressDialog to run normally but i intentionally cut off my data plan (but my WIFI and 3G are on) so that the app believes that network is available, i need the user to get a message through a Toast or something after the asynctask finishes running telling them that there's connection difficulty. Presently what happens is that when the asynctask is done running and there is no actual internet service, the progressDialog dismisses and the app crashes

Ok I have added the code, and let me rephrase the question:

What i need basically is just a response from the activity via a Toast or something just like when you are trying to log into your twitter or facebook app and the network is not steady or slow, after a while the dialog progressDialog dismisses and you get a message that the network is having some difficulty. This is different from checking if there is a WI-FI or Mobile Connectivity on your phone (I already handled that). The situation am simulating is when connection is in progress but the connection is slow, or not consistent or you have no data plan subscribed

Here's the code for the activity:

```
package com.insidetown;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List; 
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;





    public class Result extends ListActivity {

        //final String category = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).getSelectedItem().toString();
        //final String location = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2)).getSelectedItem().toString();
        String category = "Flowers";
        String location = "Washington";

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        //private static final int LONG_DELAY = 7500; // 3.5 seconds

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

        // url to get all products list
        private String url_all_products = "http://theURL.com.ng/123.php?category="+category+"&location="+location;
  category="+category+"&location="+location;

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "data"; 
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.result);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();      

            // Loading results in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            //ListView lv = getListView();


        }


        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        Result.this,
                        null,
                        "loading...",
                        true,
                        true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                Toast.makeText(Result.this,
                                        "Operation Cancelled.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                // cancel the AsyncTask here!
                                LoadAllProducts.this.cancel(true);
                            }
                        }
                        );


                }


            /**
             * getting results from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                //Log.d("Results: ", json.toString());


                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // results returned
                        // Getting Array of results
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through results
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable

                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                            String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                            map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    }       

                    else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops! There seems to be a problem", 3).show(); 

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                // dismiss the dialog after getting results
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                Result.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,
                                        TAG_ADDRESS, TAG_PHONE},
                                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.phone });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }     

        }
    }
```

@ Lazy Ninja and @ Chris Stratton, Pls find the logcat of the crash below:

```
05-08 09:56:25.180: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:26.470: D/dalvikvm(872): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K, 3% free 3611K/3716K, paused 131ms, total 140ms
05-08 09:56:27.530: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:28.800: W/System.err(872): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "insidetown.com.ng": No address associated with hostname
05-08 09:56:28.860: W/System.err(872):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
05-08 09:56:28.860: W/System.err(872):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-08 09:56:28.860: W/System.err(872):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-08 09:56:28.860: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-08 09:56:28.860: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-08 09:56:28.870: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-08 09:56:28.870: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-08 09:56:28.870: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-08 09:56:28.870: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-08 09:56:28.890: W/System.err(872):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-08 09:56:28.890: W/System.err(872):  at com.insidetown.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:67)
05-08 09:56:28.910: W/System.err(872):  at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:118)
05-08 09:56:28.910: W/System.err(872):  at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:1)
05-08 09:56:28.910: W/System.err(872):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-08 09:56:28.950: W/System.err(872):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-08 09:56:28.950: W/System.err(872):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-08 09:56:28.950: W/System.err(872):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-08 09:56:29.000: W/System.err(872):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-08 09:56:29.000: W/System.err(872):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-08 09:56:29.030: W/System.err(872): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
05-08 09:56:29.040: W/System.err(872):  at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
05-08 09:56:29.040: W/System.err(872):  at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
05-08 09:56:29.040: W/System.err(872):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
05-08 09:56:29.070: W/System.err(872):  ... 18 more
05-08 09:56:29.070: E/Buffer Error(872): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
05-08 09:56:29.100: E/JSON Parser(872): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-08 09:56:29.100: W/dalvikvm(872): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a59b90)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Process: com.insidetown, PID: 872
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:127)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Result.java:1)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-08 09:56:29.220: E/AndroidRuntime(872):  ... 4 more
05-08 09:56:29.260: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 1072 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:30.040: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 471 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:31.550: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 606 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:31.680: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.insidetown.Result has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b4df2280 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-304,96} that was originally added here
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at com.insidetown.Result$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(Result.java:88)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at com.insidetown.Result.onCreate(Result.java:67)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
05-08 09:56:33.870: E/WindowManager(872):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 09:56:33.870: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 809 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:34.130: I/Choreographer(872): Skipped 162 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 09:56:35.740: I/Process(872): Sending signal. PID: 872 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should try to add minimal code snippets to showcase the problem you are having.

Comment: I have added the code, pls take a look. What i need basically is just a response from the app just like when you are trying to log into your twitter or facebook app and the network is not steady or slow, after a while the dialog progressDialog disisses and you get a message that the network is having some difficulty. This is different from checking if there is a WI-FI or Mobile Connectivity on your phone (I already handled that). The situation am simulating is when the connection is slow, or not consistent or you have no data plan subscribed

Comment: Set a timer, cancel it if the network operation completes.  If the network opeation doesn't, the timer will fire and you can display your error message and cancel or ignore the async task.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() )` on doInBackground() method, not on onPostExecute because onPostExecute is running on the main UI thread.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oops! There seems to be a problem", 3).show(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: @ Lazy Ninja Hi, just tried your suggestion but the app crashed

Comment: @user3591264 - that's not a fair report.  If it crashed, you must supply the crash log.  And this code will not crash if reasonably used - the crash is your mistake, not Lazy Ninja's.

Comment: @ Chris Stratton I don't think I sounded like I was blaming @Lazy Ninja, just told him what happened so he can guide me more. I've posted the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check by adding

```
    if (isConnectingToNetwork()) {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        urlc.connect();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    }
```

isConnectingToNetwork() runs a check if there is *Wifi or Mobile connectivity*, and if true you will send a test URL connection to google and wait for reply

Comment: I have already done that, I check for Wifi or Mobile Connectivity before the AsyncTask starts. The situation am talking about is when there is Wifi or Mobile connectivity but the server is not responding or the network is very slow or the process is taking too long or there is no data left on your internet subscription.